# How to use multiple timers in allegro?

Tags: timer, allegro, allegro5

```
if( ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
```

This is the statement in the event loop to check if the incoming event is a timer event.

But all timers would generate this same event, so how do you have multiple timers going at once? How do you differentiate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is a union. See all the properties [here](http://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/ALLEGRO_EVENT).

You want `ev.timer.source` (or `ev.any.source`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example, Assuming you have two `ALLEGRO_TIMER`s(`timer_one`, `timer_two`) :

To respond to each timer:

```
if(ev.timer.source == timer_one) { //Timer one listener
//Code...
}


if(ev.timer.source == timer_two) { //Timer two listener
//Code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with this for the longest time and I found out I just forgot to include `al_start_timer(alTimer);` in my update. Stupid mistake but it could cost you some time if you forget it.